# Spaceship (<=>) operator with iterator implementation results in error: '+' cannot add two pointers

Tags: c++, c++20

This is all I have, and of course, the rest of the typical `class` with constructor, destructor, etc. However, the C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2022 gives me this error:

> CS2110 '+' cannot add two pointers.

This makes sense, given my private declaration within this class. However, I am not sure, how this can be resolve properly? In my other implementations, where the actual size isn't a **pointer**, but a **size** of type `size_t`, this has worked perfectly fine.

Private variables:

```
T* m_ptr;
size_t* m_counter;
```

Iteration code:

```
// Implemented C++ 11 range-based support.
iterator begin() noexcept { return m_ptr; }
iterator end() noexcept { return (m_ptr + m_counter); }
const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(m_ptr); }
const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(m_ptr + m_counter); }
```

The code for the spaceship (`<=>`) operator:

```
friend auto operator<=>(const SharedPtr& lhs, const SharedPtr& rhs) 
    {
        auto left = lhs.begin();
        auto right = rhs.begin();

        for (; left != lhs.end() && right != rhs.end(); ++left, ++right) {
            if (*left < *right)
                return std::strong_ordering::less;
            if (*left > *right)
                return std::strong_ordering::greater;
        }

        if (left == lhs.end())
            if (right == rhs.end())
                return std::strong_ordering::equivalent;
            else
                return std::strong_ordering::less;
        else
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
    }
```

Comment: Why is `m_counter` a pointer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Either make `m_counter` not a pointer or dereference it to get at the size?

Comment: Adding a pointer to another pointer is invalid in all circumstances and here you even try to add pointers of different types (a `T*` and a `size_t*`). What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: @user17732522, after dereferencing, I now get: `C2676 binary '<': 'const T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator` for the follow: `(*left < *right)` and `(*left > *right)` inside the spaceship operator.

Comment: Don't deref `m_ptr`

Comment: @AlbinM I am talking about `m_counter` in `end`, not the spaceship operator. That seems to be a completely unrelated error. Also, as other's have mentioned, it is _very_ unlikely that a pointer as size makes sense.

Comment: `size_t* m_counter;` 99.99999999% sure should be `size_t m_counter;`

Comment: @NathanOliver, the `m_counter` it is the reference counter.

Comment: @AlbinM You are using it as size of a range, not as a reference counter.

Comment: @user17732522, I use it like this, `m_counter = new size_t(1)`.

Comment: @AlbinM Why? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @AlbinM: We know how pointers and heap allocation work. What's confusing is what the value being pointed to *means*. If it is a reference count (ie: the number of objects referencing the `T` in the shared pointer), then your `end` function makes no sense. And if it is a size of an array, then the name is non-indicative. Basically, it seems like you have your wires crossed.

Comment: @user17732522, read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: @AlbinM: We know how shared pointers work. Our point is that your implementation of them doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I have written a `SharedPtr` class, as indicated by the parameters to the `operator<=>`, and in it, I have declared: see declaration, I use the m_counter to keep track of the number of references, dereferecing etc.

Comment: @AlbinM But you are not using it as a reference counter as `std::shared_ptr` would. What is the range that `begin` and `end` are supposed to mark?

Comment: @AlbinM: So why does `end` try to use `m_counter` as if it were the number of elements in an array?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I know. But, I haven't implemented `end()` before with this type of implementation i.e., a pointer as a counter, and the other pointer part (`m_ptr`) of some `T` type. I decided to post here, in case someone knows a correct way. When I implemented e.g. a **String class**, I used its `m_size` which represented: `size_t`.

Comment: @AlbinM: But again, that makes no sense. Increasing the number of objects referencing `m_ptr` does not increase the number of objects pointer to by `m_ptr`. If you have a string class, then the class itself has its own size; that has nothing to do with the reference count of a shared pointer. This whole question seems to arise from conflating the number of elements being pointed to by a particular pointer with the number of users pointing *at* a particular pointer. That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @AlbinM So why don't you have a `m_size` member here as well if `m_ptr` is supposed to point to an array?

Comment: @AlbinM, If you're trying to implement a shared pointer similar to `std::shared_ptr`, you likely want the reference counter to be something like `std::atomic<std::size_t>` (your refcount isn't safe for multiple threads) and the pointer to be a pointer to a single object, not an array. While `std::shared_ptr` does have array support, it's something you can add later and it doesn't keep the size of the array around, it gets that from `T`. Providing array support like that also requires you to store a deleter so that the array can be `delete[]`d correctly.

Comment: If we're talking `std::shared_ptr`, it also doesn't do deep comparisons. Rather it simply compares the pointer values.

Comment: In the full code you are showing now the class doesn't keep track of any size of the array that `_pointer` refers to, so `begin` and `end` don't make any sense for the class in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CS2110 '+' cannot add two pointers.
> ```

> ```
> T* m_ptr;
> size_t* m_counter;
> ```

> ```
> iterator end() noexcept { return (m_ptr + m_counter); }
> //                                      ^
> const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(m_ptr + m_counter); }
> //                                                                ^
> ```

The bug is here. You are attempting to add two pointers. Pointers cannot be added together; this is a meaningless operation and the program is ill-formed.

`operator<=>` isn't relevant in regard to this bug in other way besides it calls the broken `end` function.

> However, I am not sure, how this can be resolve properly

That depends on what you're trying to do. It depends on what `m_ptr` and `m_counter` point to respectively.

**If** `m_ptr` points to element of an array, **and** `m_counter` points to an integer that denotes the number of successive elements in the array, **and** your goal is to get a pointer past the number of elements, then you can indirect through the `m_counter` pointer to get the size, and add that to `m_ptr`:

```
iterator end() noexcept { return m_ptr + *m_counter; }
```

But that raises a new question: Why is `m_counter` a pointer? Why isn't the size of the array stored by value?

> `m_counter` it is the reference counter.

If `m_counter` isn't the number of successive elements of the element pointed by `m_ptr`, then the addition above doesn't make sense and will likely lead to undefined behaviour. In such case, don't do this.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did this. But, I now get:  I now get: `C2676 binary '<': 'const T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator` for the follow: `if(*left < *right)` and `if(*left > *right)` inside the spaceship `operator<=>`.

Comment: @AlbinM That means you have other bugs in the program in addition to the bug that you asked about.

Comment: eerorika, what't the best way to implement: operator<=> in this context then, to eliminate all the other operators?

Comment: @AlbinM `= default` is best when it does what you want.

Comment: @AlbinM Yes. In cases where `= default` does what you want the comparison to do, it is seriously the best option.

Comment: I know default, yet, didn't go that path. :P :xD